# Inserting into Datagrid using C# (from Oracle database)

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I'm trying to implement an insert into datagridview using only one textBox and a button (to enter) to get the desired name from the user to insert into the Database (Oracle). Unfortunately, I receive an error once I try to insert any type of name called:

> Error: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PROEKTBD"."BRAND"."BRAND_ID")

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76swd.png)

I don't quite understand why it takes a third variable since in the database the table only has 2.

```
CREATE TABLE Brand
(
brand_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
brand_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(brand_id)
);
```

**Trigger in sqldeveloper:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BRAND_INS 
BEFORE INSERT ON BRAND FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  :NEW.brand_id := BRAND_SEQ_brand_id.nextval;
END;
```

**Code in C#:**

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string oradb = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = " +
                "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Localhost)(PORT = 1521)) " +
                "(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) " +
                "(SERVICE_NAME = XE)));" +
                "user Id = ProektBD; password = viv1234;";
            string insertquery = "Insert into Brand VALUES (:1, :2)";


            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = insertquery;
            try
            {

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, string.Empty, ParameterDirection.Input));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("2", OracleDbType.Varchar2, txtBoxBrandName.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Brand has been added");
                con.Close();
                Close();
            }
            catch (OracleException e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e1.Message);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException e2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e2.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                cmd.Dispose();
                con.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken; however, the error appears to be complaining about the code trying to insert a non-INTEGER value into a non-null integer field. It appears that `brand_id` is defined as “INTEGER NOT NULL” and is the primary key…

```
CREATE TABLE Brand
(
  brand_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  brand_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(brand_id)
);
```

However, the parameter looks like it is trying to insert an “empty” `string` into the `brand_id` field… granted it is not `null` but it is expecting a non null INTEGER value.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, string.Empty, ParameterDirection.Input));
```

`OracleDbType.Varchar2` ... ? ... and `string.Empty` ... ? ...

Comment: Well first it was "OracleDbType.Decimal, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue));" instead of "string.Empty" and "OracleDbType.Varchar2" is for the name that will be inserted

Comment: From the table schema it looks like it should be an `OracleDbType.Int32` value and you will need to supply an INT value not a string value. Sorry if I am missing something.